# Invest in stocks or in your own company

Tags: investing, credit

One of the main rules in trading is that you shouldn't use credit to invest in shares. And I'm quite sure that if you go to the bank to ask for 50000€ and say that this will be invested in trading, the response will be negative and the banker could think that you are completely fool.

However, you can go to the bank to ask for a 50000€ credit for your own company and the response can be positive.

At the end, the difference is to invest in big companies or invest in your own company. From my perspective, invest in big companies should have less risk.

Why banks don't see that way? Is my assumption correct or I'm wrong?

Comment: The difference is that if you borrow money for your own company the banks will expect to see a business plan, interview the owner, see account records and possibly verify assets. They can't do this if you are going to invest in a random company.

Answer (score 4):

Your basic assumption is incorrect. You don't normally go to a bank to borrow money to invest, but brokerages do it all the time. It is called trading on margin.

Comment: That is not entirely true. I can go to my bank and refinance my mortgage, and borrow an extra $50,000 in order to invest in shares.

Comment: The comment that you don't normally do it doesn't mean that you can't.

Comment: Well where I come from it is done quite often, especially when the stock market is booming. In fact many banks these days provide margin lending and other loan structures specifically for investing.